# A simple Hangman game in Python

Tags: python, python-2.x, hangman

I'm a noobie in programming so I've made a simple hangman game in python and I'd like someone to tell me how I could improve the code.

edit:How could I do it using classes?

```
from sys import exit

def makeGallow(gallow):
        for i in range(8):
            gallow.append([])
        gallow[0].append(6 * '_')
        gallow[1].append(' |   |')
        for i in range(2, 7):
            gallow[i].append('     |')
        gallow[7].append(11 * '-')


gallow = list()
secret_word = raw_input("Choose a word: ").lower()
secret_wordls = list()
letters = len(secret_word)
for c in secret_word:
    secret_wordls.append(c)
blanks = list()
for i in range(len(secret_word)):
    blanks.append('_')
lettersUsed = list()
tries = 0
makeGallow(gallow)

while True:

    for i in gallow:
        print "".join(i)
    print "".join(i for i in blanks)
    used = ", ".join(i for i in lettersUsed)
    print "Letters used: " + used
    letter = raw_input("Type a letter: ").lower()
    if letter == 'quit':
        exit(1)
    elif letter in secret_word:
        letters -= 1
        if letters == 0:
            print "You won!"
            exit("Bye!")
        else:
            switch = secret_wordls.index(letter)
            blanks[switch] = letter
    elif letter not in secret_word:
        print "Wrong!"
        tries += 1
        lettersUsed.append(letter)
        if tries == 1:
            gallow[2] = ' O   |'
        elif tries == 2:
            gallow[3] = ' |   |'
        elif tries == 3:
            gallow[3] = '/|   |'
        elif tries == 4:
            gallow[3] = '/|\  |'
        elif tries == 5:
            gallow[4] = ' |   |'
        elif tries == 6:
            gallow[5] = '/    |'
        elif tries == 7:
            gallow[5] = '/ \  |'
            print "Sorry you lost :(."
            print "The word was: " + secret_word
            exit("Bye!")
    elif letter in lettersUsed:
        print "You have already typed that letter!"
        print "Try another one."
```

edit2: I found a bug where if the work had 2, 3... times the same letter it would count as one and you couldn't win. I change the while loop:

```
while True:

    for i in gallow:
        print "".join(i)
    print "".join(i for i in blanks)
    used = ", ".join(i for i in lettersUsed)
    print "Letters used: " + used
    letter = raw_input("Type a letter: ").lower()
    if letter == 'quit':
        exit("Bye")
    elif letter in secret_word:
        for i in range(secret_wordls.count(letter)):
            switch = secret_wordls.index(letter)
            blanks[switch] = letter
            secret_wordls[switch] = '-'
            letters -= 1
    elif letter not in secret_word:
        print "Wrong!"
        tries += 1
        lettersUsed.append(letter)
        if tries == 1:
            gallow[2] = ' O   |'
        elif tries == 2:
            gallow[3] = ' |   |'
        elif tries == 3:
            gallow[3] = '/|   |'
        elif tries == 4:
            gallow[3] = '/|\  |'
        elif tries == 5:
            gallow[4] = ' |   |'
        elif tries == 6:
            gallow[5] = '/    |'
        elif tries == 7:
            gallow[5] = '/ \  |'
            print "Sorry you lost :(."
            print "The word was: " + secret_word
            exit("Bye!")
    elif letter in lettersUsed:
        print "You have already typed that letter!"
        print "Try another one."
    if letters == 0:
        print "You won!"
        exit("Bye!")
```

Comment: Could you please just write a single final block of code for clarity?

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[What to do when someone answers](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)*.

Comment: Rolled it back. Again.

Comment: I can't vote the answer because I don't have enough reputation...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever I start a review, I open up [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the Python style guide.  That document is so rarely read that it is depressing.  Your naming is not in accordance with it.  From [Method Names and Instance Variables](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id44):

> Use the function naming rules: lowercase with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability.

(There's more, but it isn't pertinent here)

---

Your indentation looks good mostly, but for some reason you did eight-space indentation in `makeGallow()`.

---

In `makeGallow()`, you do a bunch of `.append()` calls, but you don't guarantee that your list was empty in the first place.  It is very easy to clear a list.  Just do `gallow[:] = []`.  As long as you are doing something like that any way, you might as well do `gallow[:] = [[] for _ in range(8)]` and take out your first `for` loop.  I used `_` as my variable name instead of `i` because it is the convention in Python to name a variable `_` when you aren't using it.

---

Your code could benefit from an [`if __name__ == '__main__':`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/419163/5827958) block.  That way, you might later create a very fancy hangman game that imports this one to use its `makeGallow` function.  As it is, importing this would start the game.  I would suggest that you define a `main` function and call it in your `if __name__ == "__main__":` block.

---

Strings are iterable.  That can be useful when making a list of each character in it.  For example, `list("foo")` is `["f", "o", "o"]`.  Therefore, you can change

> ```
> secret_wordls = list()
> for c in secret_word:
>     secret_wordls.append(c)
> ```

to

```
secret_wordls = list(secret_word)
```

and change

> ```
> blanks = list()
> for i in range(len(secret_word)):
>     blanks.append('_')
> ```

to

```
blanks = list("_" * letters)
```

Notice that I also changed `len(secret_word)` to `letters`.  You defined the variable; why not use it?  While I'm there, is `letters` really a good name?  From the name, I would expect it to be a list of characters or a string, not a number.  Maybe `word_length` would be better?

---

I see that you are using generator expressions.  That's good, but actually [a list comprehension is faster when using `str.join()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9061024/5827958).  Even better, don't bother with either.

> ```
> "".join(i for i in blanks)
> ```

could be

```
"". join(blanks)
```

for example.

---

I suggest that you add an `elif len(letter) != 1` between `if letter == "quit":` and the rest of the `elif`s.  That way, you can inform the user that he should type just one letter instead of penalizing him because what he typed isn't in your list of letters.

Th-th-th-th-that's all, folks! <sub><sup>(Don't worry; it's a quotation.)</sup></sub>